# A question regarding the Lambda function in Python

Tags: python, lambda

Why in the following code, the output is 22?

In my understanding, we have a function that needs two arguments, but it has been defined with only one! However, the first time we use it in `mydoubler = myfunc(2)`, it assigns the argument(2) to variable `n`, but the second time we use it in `print(mydoubler(11)`, it uses the argument(11) to set the value of the variable `a`! Why is that? Does Lambda work like a recursive function?

```
   def myfunc(n):
        return lambda a : a * n

   mydoubler = myfunc(2)

   print(mydoubler(11))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happens is this:

`mydoubler = myfunc(2)` is actually the same as writing `mydoubler = lambda a : a * 2`

The reason for this is that `myfunc(2)` returns `lambda a : a * 2`

So now `mydoubler = lambda a : a * 2`

Then when `mydoubler(11)` is called, it simply returns `11 * 2`

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a lambda, which is a one-liner function, NOT a number. The code below does the EXACT SAME thing, but is maybe a bit clearer as to its purpose:

```
def multiplier_factory(constant_factor):
    # Define our new function
    def multiplier(factor):
        result = constant_factor * factor
        return result
    # Return the FUNCTION, not a number
    return multiplier

doubler = multiplier_factory(2)
tripler = multiplier_factory(3)

print (doubler(1))  # prints 2
print (tripler(1))  # prints 3

print (doubler('a'))  # prints 'aa'
print (tripler('a'))  # prints 'aaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

lambda a: a * n is the same of:

```
def somefunction(a):
    return a * n
```

When you called myfunc(2) you dynamically created a function that is the same of:

```
def somefunction(a):
    return a * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`myfunc` returns a function. So `mydoubler` is a function and is described by `lamda a : a * 2`. Then you call that function with the argument 22 and so naturally 11 * 2 = 22 is printed. Lambda functions are not per se recursive, they are just a shorter way of writing a simple function. In your case you can also write:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def multiplier(a):
        return a * n

    return multiplier
```